# ObjectQuery extensions from managed C++/CLI

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I'm trying to move a project over to using Entity Framework, but to make it more fun, the project is in C++/CLR.

I've got a query

```
ObjectQuery<myData::Facility^>^ facQ = myContext->FacilitySet;
```

and I want to do this

```
int n = facQ.Count()
```

But I can't because c++ doesn't recognise extension methods using C# syntax. facQ->Count() doesn't work.

[Using C# extension methods from managed C++/CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349674/using-c-sharp-extension-methods-from-managed-c-cli) shows the answer for user-defined extensions; but in this case, the extension is part of the .NET framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb349034%28v=vs.90%29.aspx.

Any ideas?

(I'm using visual studio 2008, and .NET 3.5).

Comment: You just need to find the namespace and class that static method is defined in

Comment: @YochaiTimmer okay, how do I do that?  it's not on the MSDN page, and System::Data::Objects::ObjectQuery doesn't seem to have it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System::Data::Objects::ObjectQuery implements `IEnumerable<T>`. The Count() method you see in C# is from the System::Linq::Enumerable class.

```
using namespace System::Linq;

int n = Enumerable::Count(facQ);
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643734/how-to-use-linq-in-c-cli-in-vs-2010-net-4-0/5645267#5645267), which shows a couple examples of calling other extension methods in that class.