# Getting an array of bytes out of Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer

Tags: c++, stream, windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012

I have an object that implements the interface `Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer`, and I want to get an array of bytes out of it, however while looking at the documentation this interface looks pretty useless, and the documentation does not offer any reference to any other class that could be combined with this interface to achieve my purpose. All I have found so far with google is a reference to the .Net class [WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.windowsruntime.windowsruntimebufferextensions(v=vs.110).aspx) but I am using C++ so this is also a dead end.

Can someone give a hint on how to get an array of bytes from `Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer` in C++?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use IBufferByteAccess, through exotic COM casts:

```
byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ buffer)
{
   // Cast to Object^, then to its underlying IInspectable interface.

   Object^ obj = buffer;
   ComPtr<IInspectable> insp(reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(obj));

   // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.
   ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
   ThrowIfFailed(insp.As(&bufferByteAccess));

   // Retrieve the buffer data.

   byte* pixels = nullptr;
   ThrowIfFailed(bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels));

   return pixels;

}
```

Code sample copied from http://cm-bloggers.blogspot.fi/2012/09/accessing-image-pixel-data-in-ccx.html

Comment: I changed my implementation and I am using this approach now since it improves the performance of my app. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

This is a C++/CX version:

```
std::vector<unsigned char> getData( ::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ buf )
{
    auto reader = ::Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(buf);

    std::vector<unsigned char> data(reader->UnconsumedBufferLength);

    if ( !data.empty() )
        reader->ReadBytes(
            ::Platform::ArrayReference<unsigned char>(
                &data[0], data.size()));

    return data;
}
```

For more information see [Array and WriteOnlyArray (C++/CX)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh700131.aspx).

Answer (score 9):

Also check this method:

IBuffer -> Platform::Array
[CryptographicBuffer.CopyToByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.copytobytearray)

Platform::Array -> IBuffer
[CryptographicBuffer.CreateFromByteArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.cryptographicbuffer.createfrombytearray.aspx)

As a side note, if you want to create `Platform::Array` from simple C++ array you could use `Platform::ArrayReference`, for example:

```
char* c = "sdsd";
Platform::ArrayReference<unsigned char> arraywrapper((unsigned char*) c, sizeof(c));
```

Comment: Thanks this saved me a headache!, for reference, ArrayReference is in the Platform namespace.

Comment: WARNING: sizeof(c) will produce the size of the pointer, not the length of the string.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned before, `WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions` from the namespace `System::Runtime::InteropServices::WindowsRuntime` is only available for .Net applications and not for native C++ applications.

A possible solution would be to use `Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader`:

```
void process(Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer^ uselessBuffer)
{
    Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader^ uselessReader =
             Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader::FromBuffer(uselessBuffer);
    Platform::Array<Byte>^ managedBytes = 
                         ref new Platform::Array<Byte>(uselessBuffer->Length);
    uselessReader->ReadBytes( managedBytes );                               
    BYTE * bytes = new BYTE[uselessBuffer->Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < uselessBuffer->Length; i++)
        bytes[i] = managedBytes[i];

    (...)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since this question is tagged [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), here's a solution using [C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/). It essentially does the same as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14172579/1889329) under the hood, but is way more accessible. The (undocumented) `data()` helper on the `IBuffer` projection does all the heavy lifting:

```
uint8_t* GetPointerToPixelData(::winrt::Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer const& buffer)
{
    return buffer.data();
}
```

There is unfortunately no official documentation (yet), and I only stumbled across this in the sample code for the [`WritableBitmap.PixelBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.pixelbuffer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Media_Imaging_WriteableBitmap_PixelBuffer) property (make sure to select *"C++/WinRT"* from the language dropdown at the top right).

An identical solution (by explicitly querying for the `IBufferByteAccess` interface) is also available from that documentation entry when selecting *"C++/CX"* from the language dropdown.

---

**Update 2022-10-15**

Since writing this answer the documentation has been updated. The [`winrt` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/winrt) documentation now has a section called [C++/WinRT functions that extend Windows Runtime APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/winrt#cwinrt-functions-that-extend-windows-runtime-apis) that lists Windows Runtime types alongside the C++/WinRT functions available in addition to the interface projections.

The [IBuffer C++/WinRT extension functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.ibuffer#cwinrt-extension-functions) link takes you to the respective section in the `IBuffer` interface documentation, with the `data()` function properly documented.

Answer (score 3):

This should work with WinRT extensions:

```
// Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader
// buffer is assumed to be of type Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer
// BYTE = unsigned char

DataReader^ reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(buffer);

BYTE *extracted = new BYTE[buffer->Length];

// NOTE: This will read directly into the allocated "extracted" buffer
reader->ReadBytes(Platform::ArrayReference<BYTE>(extracted, buffer->Length));

// ... do something with extracted...

delete [] extracted; // don't forget to free the space
```

Comment: There is almost no documentation about this class Platform::ArrayReference, where did you find this information if I may ask?

Comment: Here's an example from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700131.aspx "Use ArrayReference to avoid copying data"

Answer (score -1):

[Use the extension method like a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1349687/6210):

```
IBuffer *buffer;
array<unsigned char>^ result= System::Runtime::InteropServices::WindowsRuntime::WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions::ToArray(buffer);
```

Comment: @user787913, I was confused at first as well.

Comment: @MSN WindowsRuntimeBufferExtensions is a class in .Net framework, it cannot be used from a native C++ application