# how to copy bytes into a Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer or IBuffer for ouput via Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter::WriteBuffer()

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017, c++-cx

I am working with a sample UWP C++/CX program that creates two UDP network communication threads which are sending data to each other using `Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter` and `Windows::Storage::Streams::DataReader` while updating a displayed window showing the data going back and forth.

The initial implementation using `Platform::String` variables along with `DataWriter->WriteString()` worked fine. However now I want to implement a binary protocol that has variable length buffers containing various types of information.

`DataReader->ReadBuffer()` and `DataWriter->WriteBuffer()` requires a `Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer`.

To access the Buffer returned by `ReadBuffer()` I am using a function whose source if found on the web at [Obtaining pointers to data buffers (C++/CX)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/obtaining-pointers-to-data-buffers-c-cx)  which is similar to an answer in [Getting an array of bytes out of Windows::Storage::Streams::IBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11853838/getting-an-array-of-bytes-out-of-windowsstoragestreamsibuffer)

```
#include <robuffer.h>  

byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ pixelBuffer, unsigned int *length)
{
    if (length != nullptr)
    {
        *length = pixelBuffer->Length;
    }
    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.  
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(pixelBuffer)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferByteAccess));

    // Retrieve the buffer data.  
    byte* pixels = nullptr;
    bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels);
    return pixels;
}
```

However I have been unable to find out how to copy a native struct into a Buffer so that it can be sent out using `DataWriter->WriteBuffer()`.

If I have some struct of binary data, how can I copy the contents of this struct into the output `Windows::Storage::Streams::Buffer` for use with `DataWriter->WriteBuffer()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the same function that can be used to obtain a pointer to the `Buffer` memory area to copy data from the `Buffer` into a native memory area can also be used to obtain a pointer that can be used to copy data into the `Buffer`. See [Obtaining pointers to data buffers (C++/CX).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/obtaining-pointers-to-data-buffers-c-cx) and see as well [COM Coding Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff485839(v=vs.85).aspx) for information about the `IID_PPV_ARGS()` macro and the ATL smart pointer class `CComPtr`. See [QueryInterface: Navigating in an Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms687230) as well.

`ComPtr` is the WRL version of the ATL `CComPtr` (see [Native WinRT Inheritance](https://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2011/09/25/native-winrt-inheritance) as well as [Windows Runtime C++ Template Library (WRL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh438466.aspx) which has links to a variety of supporting topics for WRL and WinRT).

> (`ComPtr` is a WRL smart pointer. It automates some aspects of COM that
>   otherwise get tedious fast. It’s similar to ATL’s `CComPtr`, although
>   some operations that `CComPtr` performed implicitly now require explicit
>   code, largely because those implicit operations were responsible for a
>   lot of bugs in code written by people who didn’t really understand how
>   `CComPtr` works. With the new `ComPtr`, a failure to understand how it
>   works is more likely to lead to a compiler error than a runtime bug.)

as well as [ComPtr in the DirectXTK wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr)

> `Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr` is a C++ template smart-pointer for COM objects
>   that is used extensively in Windows Runtime (WinRT) C++ programming.
>   It works in Win32 desktop applications as well. It is similar to ATL's
>   `CComPtr` with some useful improvements. `Microsoft::WRL:::ComPtr` is in
>   the Windows 8.x SDK and Windows 10 SDK, which, unlike ATL, is
>   available when using the Express versions of Visual Studio. It is used
>   extensively in DirectX Tool Kit to properly handle COM reference
>   counting maintenance.

```
#include <robuffer.h>  

byte* GetPointerToPixelData(IBuffer^ pixelBuffer, unsigned int *length)
{
    if (length != nullptr)
    {
        *length = pixelBuffer->Length;
    }
    // Query the IBufferByteAccess interface.  
    Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IBufferByteAccess> bufferByteAccess;
    reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(pixelBuffer)->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferByteAccess));

    // Retrieve the buffer data.  
    byte* pixels = nullptr;
    bufferByteAccess->Buffer(&pixels);
    return pixels;
}
```

**Warning:** You must ensure that you do not exceed the capacity of the memory allocated to the `Buffer` (you can check the `Capacity` attribute of the buffer). After copying from a native variable into the `Buffer` you must also set the `Length` attribute to the actual number of bytes of data set into the `Buffer`.

For example:

```
// test structs for binary data to parse.
struct struct1 {
    unsigned char uchMajorClass;
    unsigned char uchMinorClass;
    long  lVal1;
};

void testfunc (IOutputStream^ outputStream)
{
    auto dataWriter = ref new DataWriter(outputStream);

    struct1 myStruct1 = { 1, 11,0 };

    Buffer ^myBuffer = ref new Buffer(sizeof(struct1));  // allocate Buffer of desired size

    unsigned int  len;
    struct1 *sp = (struct1 *)GetPointerToPixelData(myBuffer, &len);  // get native pointer

    // we could use myBuffer->Capacity at this point to check the capacity or
    // max size in bytes of the buffer.
    *sp = myStruct1;                // copy data from native into the Buffer
    myBuffer->Length = sizeof(*sp); // set the data length
    dataWriter->WriteBuffer(myBuffer);

}
```

Comment: You could also just use `dataWriter->WriteBytes()` to write out bytes, and use `Platform::Array` to hold the data.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT thank you for the suggestion. Is there a `ReadBytes()` as well? It looks like there is one with arguments of a `Byte` array and a max size or capacity. I guess I got fixed on the `Buffer` approach working with an example that started with `String`. I suppose the nice thing about the `Buffer` approach is that dealing with variable packet sizes, this is a UDP client/server, `Buffer` may be easier. However the original application I am replicating used a single large buffer size for the UDP network traffic.

Comment: Yes, there is a [`ReadBytes()` method on the `DataReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader.readbytes). In IDL it is represented as a {pointer, size} pair of arguments, but it should project as `Platform::Array` as well.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT thanks for the link as there is a link on that page to a [Microsoft GitHub area with sample applications](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/DataReaderWriter).