# How use LINQ in C++\CLI managed codes

Tags: arrays, linq, visual-studio-2015, c++-cli, managed

There is a simple **managed** code in **C++\CLI** :

```
cli::array<String^>^ ar= gcnew cli::array<String^>{"Stack","Over","Flow", "Over" };
```

Now i want to sort this array using with **LINQ**.
How use LINQ in C++\CLI managed codes?

---

In regular .net & c# language programming way we act like this :

```
string[] ar = new string[] {"Stack","Over","Flow", "Over" };
string[] ar_sort = ar.OrderByDescending(s => s).ToArray();
int count = ar_sort.Where(s => s.Contains("Over")).Count();
```

Now i want convert them to **C++\CLI** managed :

```
cli::array<String^>^ ar= gcnew cli::array<String^>{"Stack","Over","Flow", "Over" };   
... What about this line????   
... And What about this line????
```

---

Based on this link :
[How to use LINQ in C++/CLI - in VS 2010/.Net 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5643734/how-to-use-linq-in-c-cli-in-vs-2010-net-4-0)

> C++/CLI does not support LINQ syntax.

But this link is for 2011 year & related to VS 2010.
My VS version is 2015.
So This Question is not **duplicate**.
Please don't vote to close.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1349674/94928

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015. That link is for VS 2010. No duplicate man...

Comment: It's still the same answer: The Linq methods are extension methods on a specific class, so just call them as regular static methods.

Comment: C++/CLI didn't evolve since then, unfortunately. Just write `Enumerable::ToArray(Enumerable::OrderByDescending(ar, gcnew Func<string, string>(&YourOwnIdentityFunctionThere)));` etc. Yes, that's ugly.

Comment: So would you please ReWrite my codes in this way...

Comment: I just did that for the first line, the second one is up to you.

Comment: What is YourOwnIdentityFunctionThere??? Also What is Func<string, string>?

Comment: `YourOwnIdentityFunctionThere` is a function you have to write, which takes a `System::String` parameter and simply returns it as is, the equivalent of `s => s` in C#. As for the other one it's `System::Func<System::String, System::String>`. I can't help you much more if you lack a basic grasp of the language.